# VS Code terminal theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

I Installed Cobalt2 theme and I have the yellow design as shown on the top part. But the bottom blue and green with repository name is not seen. How can I make my terminal look like this ? I was following this [url](https://dev.to/nickytonline/my-visual-studio-code-setup-2ima)

[image]

Comment: From the post: "I use Fish Shell and Fisherman with the Agnoster theme"

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the screenshot is rendered by [Oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh), not VSCode.

You can read a detailed guide on how to set it up like that [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-configure-your-macos-terminal-with-zsh-like-a-pro-c0ab3f3c1156/)

Comment: In this video VScode has it https://youtu.be/F2DBSH2VoHQ?t=276

Comment: Yes, just follow the tutorial from my second link. Oh my zsh will also then be used in VSCode (Or any other terminal)